# Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

im posting here because ive done like 12hours searching and trying things to resolve my issue , but just cant find the solution.

Here is a screen of my errors: 
[React native debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgqsK.png)

I have followed the facebook developers step for IOS, followed instruction of FBSDK github, i've linked libraries...

still have errors..

Hope someone will help me out

Regards.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/322#issuecomment-271457311 It helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: @e1dar thanks its helped me .

Answer (score 2):

> [e1dar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5759314/e1dar) answers your question but it was a comment so i'm answering the question as a post!

You can install the latest version with this fix from github right now with:

`react-native install "facebook/react-native-fbsdk"`

This will write to your `package.json` file:

`"react-native-fbsdk": "github:facebook/react-native-fbsdk"`

(you'll probably want to `react-native uninstall react-native-fbsdk` to uninstall and unlink the currently released version).

I also had to manually run `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`, then remove and re-add `LIBRCTFBSDK.a` from `Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries` in XCode.

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/322#issuecomment-271457311)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to solve this issue here by changing my podfile for the fsdk to:

```
pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :subspecs => ['Core', 'Login', 'Share'], :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem too

Go through these steps to solve the problem:

1. Make sure your react-native-fbsdk is linked and install.
2. Make sure there are Bolts, ShareKit, CoreKit and LoginKit in your project framework.
3. If you run into this error, its very likely that your framework is in the wrong path.
4. Open your project with Xcode, go to your FBSDK framework search path.
   **note:** this is not your project framework search path, it is your FBSDK framework search path. Drag the directory of your framework to the path, just like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg7c0.png).
5. Rebuild and run your project again! Good luck