# invariant violation: Native component for RCTFBLoginButton does not exist this error is located at: in RCTFBLoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am implementing fb sdk in react native app. I have done all changes from [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started), and running in android device.

> invariant violation: Native component for RCTFBLoginButton does not exist this error is located at: in RCTFBLoginButton

I searched a lot but none helped me to get rid of this issue. referece [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17957) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874400/native-component-for-rctfbloginbutton-does-not-exist).

I think android facebook sdk verison and react facebook sdk version have mismatch, but don't know how to resolve it.

**I am stuck from hours :/**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Alert, View } from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken
} = FBSDK;

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
              <LoginButton
                publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
                onLoginFinished={
                  (error, result) => {
                    if (error) {
                      alert("login has error: " + result.error);
                    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                      alert("login is cancelled.");
                    } else {
                      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                        (data) => {
                          alert(data.accessToken.toString())
                        }
                      )
                    }
                  }
                }
                onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
            </View>
          );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

to

```
api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

in build.gradle(Module: react-native-fbsdk)